# Correcting unicode errors when printing unicode chars in a 2.7.10 app on TravisCI

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, travis-ci, python-unicode

I'm trying to print some unicode chars in a test runner using Python 2.7.10 on TravisCI.

Locally (macOS), I'm able to run it just fine by doing:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def my_test(self):
        for x in alist:
            # a long running op
            # updates item in list
            sys.stdout.write('█')

        for x in alist:
            if x.success:
                print(" ✓ pass   {}".format(x.name))
            else:
                print(" x fail   {}".format(x.name, x.err))
```

But when I push it up to TravisCI, it always fails with that pesky `ordinal not in range(128)` error.

I've tried:

- Setting a Travis env variable to `LC_ALL`: `C.UTF-8`
- Using `dist: trusty`
- Using `deploy: \ default_text_charset: 'utf-8'`
- Using `six.u()`, but that complains with `TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`

Here's my .travis.yml:

```
language: python

dist: trusty

python:
  - 2.7.10

install:
  - pip install --quiet future
  - pip install --quiet pyyaml
  - pip install --quiet dotmap

script:
  - cd appdir; python -m unittest tests

deploy:
  default_text_charset: 'utf-8'
```

Comment: Is re-encoding STDOUT (from within Python) an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, `sys.stdout.write` takes byte strings. If you give it `unicode`, it coerces them it to `str`, which apparently fails here because ASCII is used.

You can wrap `sys.stdout` in a `TextIOWrapper` (as it is done in Python 3):

```
import io
sys.stdout = io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

Save it to another name if you don't want to override `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Ah, yep, it works. Had to `from __future__ import print_function` as well.

Comment: And what's super weird, is a day after this started passing, it *stopped* passing, with `IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`. Removed the stdout redirect and kept just future's `print_function`, and THIS time it worked. 

Comment: Sounds weird, indeed... Are you sure this happens in Python 2? I'm getting `Errno 9` when calling `open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w')` in Python 3 (well, in the interacte interpreter, where it's no surprise to get problems when fiddling with the std channels).

Comment: Yep, 2.7.10 ... 

Comment: Hmm. Well, with the `print_function` you can just pass any writeable file object with the `file` keyword arg. It's more boilerplate, of course. Other options might be given through the `future` module, which you mention (not to confuse with the `__future__` statements); it allows to write 2/3 compatible code more easily through additional backports via `from builtins import ...` statements. But I have to admit that this is reaching terrain where I'm personally unexperienced.

Comment: Yeah, me too. All I know is that it didn’t work, and now it does, and frankly I’m ok with that outcome!